# What is the alternative to RecyclerView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What is the alternative to Recycle view in flutter I have tried using this code
but how to do Animination with listview widget in flutter

Is this valid?

```
 ListView(
 children: <Widget>[
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.map),
  title: Text('Map'),
),
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
  title: Text('Album'),
),
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
  title: Text('Phone'),
  ),
 ],
);
```

Comment: RecyclerView is essentially an enhanced version of a ListView. I'd assume ListView in flutter isn't the same as a RecyclerView, but a regular ListView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use animatedlist widget for animations. code example are given in the following link.

> [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html)

Comment: That link is deprecated. The new one is https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html. Next year this will probably be deprecated! lol

Comment: And you are right, your link is dead.^^

Comment: Worth noting that just the link was deprecated not the view. I was confused for a moment.

Comment: funnily enough the original link now works and the revised one is dead.

Answer (score 25):

`ListView`:

Usually this should be used with a small number of children as the List will also construct the invisible elements in the list and a large amount of elements may render this inefficient.

`ListView.builder()`:

The list items are constructed lazily, meaning only a specific number of list items are constructed and when a user scrolls ahead, the earlier ones are destroyed.

More info is [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-listview-and-scrollphysics-a-detailed-look-7f0912df2754).

Answer (score 10):

Following [flutter-for/android-devs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs)

> The recommended, efficient, and effective way to build a list uses a
>   ListView.Builder. This method is great when you have a dynamic List or
>   a List with very large amounts of data. This is essentially the
>   equivalent of RecyclerView on Android, which automatically recycles
>   list elements for you:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample App"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widgets.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              return getRow(position);
            }));
  }

  Widget getRow(int i) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Text("Row $i")),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widgets.add(getRow(widgets.length + 1));
          print('row $i');
        });
      },
    );
  }
```